# Ruby HTTP Request

Tags: ruby, file, io

Ruby

```
req = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://www.domain.com/coupons.txt'))

@play = req.body
```

req.body give me the entire page in to a string. What if I just want to read line by line? gets? Can you read line by line through a http get? Or do I just need to read a file from local?

The text file looks like this

```
1 John Ham 25,000

2 Ham John 25,000

3 Ohail Spam 25,000

4 Ted Dome 25,000

5 Di Di 25,000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the body method returns a string, I would have to assume you can use the `String#each_line` method.  Check out the documentation for [String#each_line](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000839).

Comment: Please be aware that this will still read the entire body from the socket.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to read the entire body, try using [the `Net::HTTPResponse#read_body` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTPResponse.html#M000706):

> The body is provided in fragments, as
>   it is read in from the socket.